# Composer dump-autoload in laravel seems not working

Tags: ubuntu, laravel, composer-php

I've tried to autoload my NEW classes but it's not working. I recive an error saying that my class controller does not exist. I'm working in ubuntu env. with laravel 4.2

**Composer.json**

```
    "psr-0": {
        "Controllers": "app/",
        "Stuffs": "app/"
    }
```

**app/Controllers/UserController.php**

```
<?php

namespace Controllers;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Input;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Response;

class UserController extends BaseController
{
    public function index()
    {
        $stuffs = $this->stuffs->findAllForUser($this->user, 12);

        $this->view('user.profile', compact('stuffs'));
    }
}
```

**app/routes.php**

```
Route::get('user', [ 'as' => 'user.index', 'uses' => 'UserController@index' ]);
```

I've tried to do this to autoload those class:
`composer dump-autoload -o` and even with `sudo` permission, but not working. Am I missing something? Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to reference the controller with the fully qualified name in your route:

```
Route::get('user', [ 'as' => 'user.index', 'uses' => 'Controllers\UserController@index' ]);
```

If you have many of those you can also use a [route group](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/routing#route-groups) to define the namespace:

```
Route::group(array('namespace' => 'Controllers'), function(){
    Route::get('user', [ 'as' => 'user.index', 'uses' => 'UserController@index' ]);
});
```

Comment: Makes sense. Thank you, I forgot to include it in the route group. It's working now!